# How to specify the autocomplete results in a certain country?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-places-api

I have the same autocomplete script as in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

**My include script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.8&sensor=false&libraries=geometry,places&language=&hl=&region=FR"></script>
```

**The javascript:**

```
function initAutocomplete(callback, input_s, lat_s, lng_s, label_s) {

    var input = $(input_s)[0];
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    //autocomplete.bindTo('', search_map.map);
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (place.geometry) {
            $(lat_s).val(place.geometry.location.lat());
            $(lng_s).val(place.geometry.location.lng());
            $(label_s).val(place.formatted_address);
            if (callback) {
                callback();
            }

        }
    });
}

initAutocomplete(somefunction, '#zipcode_search_input', "#search_lat", "#search_lng", "#search_address_label");
```

I'd like the results to be biased in favor of french cities. Eg: if I type "laval", I want `Laval, France` to show up first, then `Laval, Canada`.

Specifying region or `language`, `region` or `hl` in the include script doesn't help. How can I bias the results towards france ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [location biasing](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete#location_biasing):

**Change:**

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
```

**to:**

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, 
   {componentRestrictions: {country: 'fr'}});
```

---

**Edit**: componentsRestrictions actually restricts the results in a specific country. To bias the results instead (results from others countries are still shown, but with lower priority), do this:

[Grab sw and ne lat/lng here](http://universimmedia.pagesperso-orange.fr/geo/loc.htm)

```
var southWest = new google.maps.LatLng(42.97250, -3.82324);
var northEast = new google.maps.LatLng(51.64529, 5.49316);
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(southWest,northEast);
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {bounds: bounds});
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
  //...
});
```